# Auto-populate a cell based on the input of another cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016

I'm trying to create an Excel spreadsheet that auto-populates a cell based on data that I put into one cell. For instance, column E is a number that corresponds to an item. The description for the item the number represents is stored in column C on the same row as the number it corresponds to.

I'd like to be able to put in the number in Column E, and have the description in Column C be automatically filled. I already have a sheet in the same Excel workbook that has all the numbers on Column A and all of the descriptions next to it on Column B. How can I get the correct description to be pulled onto the other sheet from the number on Column A?

Comment: “a number that corresponds to an item” is ambiguous.  If `C1` is “cat”, is `E1` the number of cats that you have?  If `C1` is “car”, is `E1` the weight of your car?  If `C1` is “cheese”, is `E1` the height, weight, density or age of your cheese?  If `C1` is “Steve”, is `E1` the number of points Steve scored in the big game?  Or maybe his uniform number?  Your question makes sense only if different “items” always have different numbers, and you’ve said nothing to indicate that that is the case.

Comment: The item could be "potassium sorbate" and a number represents that item as a 7 digit number as in '7501752'

Comment: Every item has its own unique number. Much like Steve and his uniform number

Answer (score 2):

In column C, use the VLOOKUP function. It takes 3 arguments: The cell with the value you want to look up, the range of cells containing the data to be searched, and the column that the data is in.

```
=VLOOKUP(lookup_cell, range_start:range_end, value_column)
```

For your example, you have an item number in column E (lookup cell), your data is in columns A and B of another sheet (range), and the item descriptions are in column B (2) of the range. So, if your lookup cell was E1, and you had 2 items in your list on the second sheet, your formula for cell C1 could be this:

```
=VLOOKUP(E1, Sheet2!A$1:B$99, 2)
```

(Replace the `99` with the number of rows you have on Sheet2.) 
If column A had item number 1, and column B had the description "Item 1", then cell C1 would display "Item 1".

(The `$` in the range fixes the rows of the range with those numbers, so if you were to 'Fill Down' with column C, the column E in each row would feed the formula for that row's column C and be able to find the correct entry in the lookup range.)

Comment: Welcome to Super User. FYI, [your suggested edit](https://superuser.com/review/suggested-edits/945278) got rejected.  I redid the edit; thanks for pointing out the mistake.  (Unfortunately, there’s no way I can give you the 2 points you should have earned.)  Bear in mind that suggested edits are reviewed by users who have a high reputation (i.e., score) on the site, and are not necessarily experts in the subject matter of the post.  (And the people who voted to reject your edit are among the top 10 most negative reviewers.) … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  Also, reviewers are hesitant to approve edits that make technical changes unless they can verify that the edit is technically correct.   If you can identify that your edit is reversing a previous error, and is restoring the post to what the author originally wrote, that increases the chance that your edit will be accepted.

Comment: P.S. I fixed your answer here.