# Auto populate text?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, automation

I'm curious if there's a way to auto populate text in one cell based on a word or phrase entered in the cell before it.

Example:
C17 = LockBox
Then I want
D17 = An individual dropped off an envelope.

I'm also curious if I could manually alter part of that text in cell D after it populates.

Comment: 1) an `IF` formula would autopopulate, 2) you can manually alter cell D, but depending on the alteration, you would probably break functionality. Perhaps adding a new column with the alteration, then combining the new with the formula is what you want?

Comment: Well, I have several words/phrases I want to use throughout column C to populate text in column D. And it's a work log I'm using.  So, adding formulas is fine, but I can't really add other sections.

Comment: sounds like a `switch` formula will be enough and if you need to modify add this to the end of the `&"whatever text you want"`

Comment: @MichaelMorton  there are many methods few U can check from these links ,,,, [the easiest is](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/auto-populate-a-cell-with-text-based-on-another/bdee6cd5-23ba-4e62-9c55-ee164b360cbb)  and [another is](https://superuser.com/questions/1516321/auto-populate-a-cell-based-on-the-input-of-another-cell)  ,, hope these will help you. ☺